# Perl command failing if I use -e option to check whether the file exists or not

Tags: perl

I have perl version v5.8.3 installed on my windows machine.
While running a perl script having the below code, failing.

```
if(-e $file1)
```

I knew that this checks whether `file1` is present or not.
The error just shown "perl command failed". Nothing else.
Could you please help me on this

Comment: Is file1 a variable? Then it should be $file1. Otherwise if it is a literal name, "file1".

Comment: There is no standard error message (that I've ever heard of) that goes "perl command failed".

Comment: Apologies for the mistake, its if(-e $file1)
Could you please let me know a certain version of perl uses "-e" option

Comment: Show more of the code. Isn't the error message part of it?

Comment: It is not valid perl => https://eval.in/469464

Comment: You're not showing us enough to know what you're doing. Are you running it as a one-liner? Try taking a screenshot of how you run it and upload it to imgur.com, then link it here.

Comment: Re "I knew that this checks whether file1 is present or not", No, not quite. `-e $file1` can also return false if you don't have enough permission to determine if the file exists or not, and in one or two more situations.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a version of Perl from 2004. You should seriously consider upgrading.

The file test operators like `-e` have been part of Perl for a very long time. They are certainly supported by Perl 5.8.3.

You say that your error is "perl command failed". That is not an error that is generated by Perl, so I suspect there is something else going on here that you're not telling us about (presumably because you think it isn't important).

If I had to guess why your `-e` test is failing, I'd say that it's because `$file1` doesn't contain any information about the directory where the file can be found, and therefore Perl is looking in the wrong place. Perhaps you can get more information with code like this:

```
use Cwd;

if (-e $file1) {
  ...
} else {
  die "Can't find file: " . cwd() . '/' . $file1;
}
```

This will show you where Perl is looking for the file.